# Why am I seeing DBI errors on the console even though I have wrapped the DBI calls in an eval?

Tags: perl, eval, dbi

I have a database query that I am running inside an eval, to trap the error. Problem is that the error message is outputting to console, even though it is being trapped. How do I stop the error message from doing this, as I want to parse it myself and spit back my own messages?

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Pg:dbname=database;host=localhost',
    'user', 'pass', 
    {RaiseError => 1}
);

eval{
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute;
};

if($@){
    #Do my parse/print stuff here I know
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify '[PrintError](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI#PrintError_(code_ref,_inherited)) => 0' in your `connect` call (or use [HandleError](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI#HandleError_(code_ref,_inherited))):

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Pg:dbname=database;host=localhost', $user, $passwd, {
  PrintError => 0,
  RaiseError => 1,
});
```

Or to set per statement handle:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * from my_table");
$sth->{PrintError} = 0;
$sth->execute();
...etc.
```

Also, don't depend on $@ for indicating an error. A better way to use eval is:

```
my $result = eval {
  ...
  $sth->...etc.
  1;
}
unless ($result) {
  # Do error handling..log/print $@
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `HandleError` could also be used, if you're going down the (Print|Raise)Error route.

Comment: @vol7ron HandleError is also a possibility, but I've never found a good use for it since I usually just wrap blocks of code in eval { } to catch all exceptions, not just DBI errors.

Comment: You can set some of these attributes per statement handle too.

Comment: update: I now am regularly using HandleError so that I can use Carp::confess to get a stack trace.

Answer (score 14):

It's not a good idea to trap and ignore errors, whether they are fatal or not.  Also, it is not advisable to check $@ in the way you are doing it (see the questions on this site about perl exceptions for better ways to trap exceptions; I use [Try::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Try::Tiny) below, which is arguably the lightest-weight route of all).

Instead of proceeding with a DBI operation when an earlier one might have failed, you should check error conditions at every step:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Try::Tiny;

try {
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql) or die $dbh->errstr;
    $sth->execute or die $sth->errstr;
} catch {
    print "got error $_\n";
    # return from function, or do something else to handle error
};
```

And remember, *always* `use strict; use warnings;` in *every* module and script.  Your code excerpt suggests that you are not yet doing this.

Comment: My code example was the _minimum_viable_ example of what I was working with. Therefore, things like warnings and strict have been stripped out, as well as other eval statements. But thanks for playing. Your answer is saved from completely bagging on the question and a downvote by the useful link provided for Try:Tiny.

Comment: @Ben: I inferred this from `$sth = ...` rather than `my $sth = ...`. There's no need to be rude.

Comment: The same to yourself. It's quite rude to assume anything about how a script is built from 7 lines of code.

Comment: @Ben We can only see what you post.

Answer (score 2):

`eval { }` will trap a fatal error (from a `die` or `Carp::croak` call), but not a non-fatal error message (from `warn` or `carp`). To handle warning messages, see how to install a warning handler in documentation for [`%SIG`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlvar#%SIG) or [`warn`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlfunc#warn).

A trivial workaround is to use a trivial warning handler inside your `eval` block.

```
eval {
    local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub { };
    ...
};
```

See also: [`perlfaq7:` How do I temporarily block warnings?](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlfaq7#How_do_I_temporarily_block_warnings?)

Comment: Blah blah blah are you sure it's a good idea to suppress your warning messages blah blah.

Comment: **@mobrule:** I think that is what was being asked.  `local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {}` is the obvious choice.  http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/warn.html

Comment: While this is a correct solution to suppressing warnings in an `eval` block, specifying `PrintError => 0` in the `connect` method is the right way to handle the OP's situation.

Comment: They both do.  It depends on what the OP wants - both answers are valid, but doesn't DBI use `$SIG{__WARN__}` and `Carp` internally?

Comment: Instead of setting a WARN handler globally, you can use a HandleError attribute to the particular statement handle. You don't want to change what everything else is doing just because one object is causing a problem.

Comment: **@brian d foy:** which is why I suggested `HandleError` as a comment in *runrig's* selected answer.  -- btw, you're not setting it globally, you're setting it locally to the `eval` block.  If these are the only two statements being called then this is a perfect solution.  Sometimes I like using alternative solutions just as a reminder that the functionality is there, in case it could be used elsewhere, where it's more purposeful.